# ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 538983457 in class file

Tags: applet, java

Доброго времени суток! Что значит эта ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего 404 ошибка при загрузке класса. Проверьте, лежит ли класс там, откуда вы пытаетесь его вытащить.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390733/incompatible-magic-value-1008813135

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501440/incompatible-magic-value-21877456-in-class-file